# Automatic repaint of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, resize

In my gui that I have created in Java, every time I minimize the window, repaint is called and the drawing that was originally there vanishes once the window is maximized (back to normal)

So I created an action Listener to detect when the window had been minimized and then maximized for it to draw each point that was originally on the panel back to the screen.
Unfortunately, I am not getting the results that I expected. 
For some reason, when the window is maximized each point is drawn back onto the panel but the background of the entire window is black. Also, this can be very annoying for the user to have to wait for each point to be drawn back onto the screen each time they want to minimize the window.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    //Redraw plot if window is minimized
    window.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        Graphics g = dPanel.getGraphics();

        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent ev) 
        {
            boolean minimized = false;

            //If user minimizes window and then maximizes window
            if(window.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED )
            {
                minimized = true;
                System.out.println("Window minimized");
            }

            if(ev.getNewState() == Frame.NORMAL || minimized == true)
            {

                System.out.println("Window back to normal state");

                //Draw each Point back onto the screen
                for(Point i: PointArray)
                {
                    drawPoint(g, i, startColor); 
                    System.out.println("Panel Repaint");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is there some way that my code can be edited to achieve the desired results or is there a better way to do this. Basically, I just want that when the user minimizes the GUI, the painting that was there before minimization is still there once the user maximizes the window. Also, moving the window around can also cause parts of the panel to be repainted or the entire panel to be repainted.

```
    //Draws point onto panel
public void drawPoint(Graphics g, Point PointArray, Color color)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
    g.setColor(color); //g2d.setColor(Color.black); 
    g2d.drawOval((int)PointArray.a, (int)PointArray.b, 2, 2);
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to paint in `windowStateChanged()`, you should try to call [`repaint()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) which will force repaint, eventually calling `paintComponent()`. You should manage all your drawing and painting in `paintComponent()`.

Comment: @Bala, so instead of drawing each point in the windowStateChanged() method, I should just call repaint in that same block of code?

Comment: @Bala, When I do that, nothing is drawn back onto the screen.

Comment: You have overridden `paintComponent()` of your container that's doing the painting?

Comment: no, I just created a drawPoint() method. See updated post

Comment: No! in `windowStateChanged()`, you'll just have to call `repaint()` for your container. And for your container override `paintComponent()` and maybe call drawPoint() in from there.  See swing related examples in this page http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/

Comment: @kachilous: you can't guess when doing Swing-related graphics. You will want to go through the tutorials before doing something like this as doing passive graphics involves a different mind set from programming that you're use to. For startes, remove all `getGraphics()` calls on components from your program.

Comment: @Hovercraft: What if I wanted to do an active approach?

Comment: @kachilous: I would still advise you to start with passive graphics as that is the standard way to paint in Swing. Active graphics is a much smaller subset of Swing graphics and only applicable in certain situations and would require for one, a full screen application. But regardless, read the tutorials as it's all spelled out there. Start [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Also look here: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) for more advanced concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more I read on your situation and need, the more I think you should actually use getGraphics, but do not call this on a JComponent such as a JPanel. Rather you should do your drawing in a BufferedImage, and you should get the Graphics object of the BufferedImage by calling getGraphics on the BufferedImage. You can then draw this BufferedImage in a JComponent's paintComponent method with the Graphics#drawImage(...) method, or even better for its simplicity (and if you don't want to use the image as a background for a JPanel or gui), draw the Image in an ImageIcon that is displayed in a JLabel. One caveat though is if you get your Graphics object in ths way, don't forget to dispose of it when you're done.

Comment: Seems straightforward enough. Thanks

Comment: @kachilous, boy this is annoying. I gave you a working example of how to draw using a BufferedImage yesterday. It did almost exacatly what you wanted except it drew rectangles  and it looks like you are tying to draw ovals. Again today I reminded you of that solution and yet you ignored my answer twice. I wasted my time twice. It won't happen again!!!

Comment: @camickr: Sorry I wasted your time.

Answer (score 3):

> I just want that when the user minimizes the GUI, the painting that was there before minimization is still there once the user maximizes the window.

I gave you the answer in your previous question (about combo boxes).

You even thanked me for the suggestions.

So try implementing the suggestion BEFORE posting a follow up quesiton.

Comment: I've done that now, but the problem is that I can't iterate through each point to be drawn in the paintComponent() method. And also because of how my drawPoint() method is set up, it would be difficult to override the paintComponent() method with those same parameters

Comment: You've done what??? You are still using getGraphics()! You also haven't read (or implemented) the suggestion from Custom Painting Approaches which give two approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: In my current implmementation, that is no longer used. All I do is when windowStateListener() detects that the window has been minimized and then maximized it calls repaint(), which calls the paintComponent() method. Then from inside the paintComponent method, I call my drawPoint() method. But to redraw each point I have to use an iterator to iterate through each point and draw it to the panel.

Comment: There is no need to use a WindowStateListener. I gave you 2 working approaches.

Comment: I guess I'm just having difficulty translating that implementation to my program. I'll keep looking at it though. Thanks

Comment: @kachilous: You understand that the reason you lose your graphics on minimize and restore is because you are using getGraphics() which gives you a temporary and unstable graphics object, one that won't persist on the next re-draw. So your use of a WindowListener is a kludge to fix a bug of your own creation. If you listen to our advice, you won't have the problem and won't need this kludge.

Comment: @Hovercraft: Oh ok. That makes sense. Because esentially what I am doing is within my simulation, I have: Graphics g = dPanel.getGraphics();
which allows me to iterate through all points and draw them to the screen after the simulation is done running. But the thing is, is that one of the parameters that needs to be passed into to my drawPoint() method is a graphics object.

Comment: @So I think what I have to do is figure out a way to pass in a graphics object into drawPoint() that will be stable enough for the graphics to persist on minimize and restore

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a way to force the repaint of a `JPanel` and all its components. Instead of doing any special work, just call your `JPanels.setVisible(false)`, then followed by `setVisible(true)`. It will redraw everything! You won't see any flicker, just like a magic.